# Cocoa popUp window animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa, nswindow

I want to make popup window animation like when you try create new project in xcode:

[image]

I have been looking for documentation or examples but so far I have not found anything. Any of you knows how can I build this window popup animation?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about making a panel appear over the main window, sliding down?

In this case it's simple: make an NSWindow or NSPanel in Interface Builder, then connect it to an IBOutlet in your AppDelegate or your view controller.

Let's say the new outlet is named "myNewPanel", then you can call it on your window:

```
myExistingWindow.beginSheet(myNewPanel, completionHandler: nil)
```

And to close it:

```
myExistingWindow.endSheet(myNewPanel)
```

Comment: in the same storyboard or it's own?

Comment: @dylan It doesn't change anything - the idea is to use an IBOutlet *or* any object holding your window - the important part is to call `endSheet` on the panel, from the window object. If this still doesn't work for you I could reopen your question - if you add specific troubleshooting information about how this solution doesn't work for you and how you tried to use it -, of course. But sincerely, just try it, it's easy to achieve.